# Maven Cannot Resolve Local Dependency

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a maven project with an in-project repository with an external jar file.
 I used the install command to install the jar file into the in-porject repository 
  and when I checked in the repository the jar file was installed
 i also added the dependency configuration in the pom file. 
 But when I run the mvn compile file.
 I get the error that mvn cannot resolve the dependency

this is the Pom snippet:

```
        <repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
</repository>
```

this is the dependency in POM

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints</groupId>
      <artifactId>Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

this is the  error message :

[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/309M

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com-boundingbox-box: Could not resolve
 dependencies for project com.boundingbox.box:com-boundingbox-box:jar:1.0-SNAPSH
OT: Could not find artifact Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine-Gest
urePoints:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
```

Does anybody have any suggestion about this error.

this is the error message after using the U and X switches

```
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for file://C:\U
sers\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-initialtheta-theta/repo
Downloading: file://C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-initialtheta-theta/repo
/Com/RubineEngine/GesturePoints/Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mave
n-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\FAISAL\.m2\repository\Com\Rubi
neEngine\GesturePoints\Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints\1.0-SNAPSHOT\resolver-stat
us.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo
.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/
Downloading: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/Com/RubineEngine/Gesture
Points/Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\FAISAL\.m2\repository\Com\Rubi
neEngine\GesturePoints\Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints\1.0-SNAPSHOT\resolver-stat
us.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine-
GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in typesafe (http://repo.typesafe.
com/typesafe/releases/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine-
GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in lib (file://C:\Users\FAISAL\Des
ktop\disaster\com-initialtheta-theta/repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-Rubin
eEngine-GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during th
is session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine-GestureP
oints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/relea
ses/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted unti
l the update interval of typesafe has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-Rubin
eEngine-GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during th
is session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine-GestureP
oints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in file://C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster
\com-initialtheta-theta/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will
 not be reattempted until the update interval of lib has elapsed or updates are
forced
```

Looks like the system is getting confuse between two repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check, if the groupId/artifactId are set correctly in the pom file of the libs in your project's repository (i.e. ${project.baseDir}\repo\Com....\1.0-SNAPSHOT\Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints.pom)
2. To get rid of "resolution will  not be reattempted until the update interval of lib has elapsed or updates are forced" error you need to delete the folders from your local repository (usually ~/.m2), i.e. ~/.m2/Com/RubineEngine.

Comment: Thank you. After some frustrating and confused couple of hours later, my problem got solved. No 2. was the reason for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing snapshots enabled to true.

```
<snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
```

Comment: Just changed the snapshot enabled to true but I still get the same error when I run the compile. Do you have any other possible suggestion.

Comment: try executing `mvn help:effective-pom` and see whether the url of the repo points to the correct one.

Comment: when I used the mvn help:effective-pom command I get the build success message. Hope that is what you suggested

Comment: nope. Check the output of that command to see whether `<url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>` is getting substituted properly.

Comment: yes I just checked and the url points to the correct location of the external jar. Also the jar can be imported into a class like any other library. But i still get the compile error. I use the eclipse juno IDE for the project just to let u know.

Comment: the url should point to your local maven repo and not the jar. try `mvn -U -X compile` X is for enabling debug

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17652/discussion-between-ajay-george-and-faisal-abdulai)

Comment: I have checked the mvn with U and X switches and have added the debuginfo to the question as edit. Looks like the mvn is confused between two repositories