# Maven Dependency error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maven Cannot Resolve Local Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760715/maven-cannot-resolve-local-dependency)

I am using maven 3 with eclispe juno.

after creating the maven project , I used the eclipse pluggin 
to generate eclipse files and import the project into eclipse.

I have added an jar that I have created to the maven project.

the jar file is installed to the project local repository. 
that is a file called repo at the project base directory.

the install:install-file command was used to add the jar to the repo file,
 the jar dependency was then added to the Pom file of the project.

At the eclipse IDE I am able to import the jar file as 
any other library importation .

However when I run the mvn compile command , 
I get a dependency error and maven says it 
cannot find the jar file . I provide the codes below.

his is the POM repo configuration

```
    <repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
</repository>
```

this is the dependency configuration

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints</groupId>
      <artifactId>Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

When the compile is runned with the U and X switches , the following error is presented

```
[DEBUG] ======================================================================= 
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for file://C:\U 
sers\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-initialtheta-theta/repo 
Downloading: file://C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-initialtheta-theta/repo 
/Com/RubineEngine/GesturePoints/Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mave 
n-metadata.xml 
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\FAISAL\.m2\repository\Com\Rubi 
neEngine\GesturePoints\Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints\1.0-SNAPSHOT\resolver-stat 
us.properties 
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for repo 
.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/ 
Downloading: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/… 
Points/Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\FAISAL\.m2\repository\Com\Rubi 
neEngine\GesturePoints\Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints\1.0-SNAPSHOT\resolver-stat 
us.properties 
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine- 
GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in typesafe (repo.typesafe. 
com/typesafe/releases/) 
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine- 
GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in lib (file://C:\Users\FAISAL\Des 
ktop\disaster\com-initialtheta-theta/repo) 
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-Rubin 
eEngine-GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during th 
is session. 
[DEBUG] Failure to find Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine-GestureP 
oints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/… 
ses/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted unti 
l the update interval of typesafe has elapsed or updates are forced 
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-Rubin 
eEngine-GesturePoints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during th 
is session. 
[DEBUG] Failure to find Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints:Com-RubineEngine-GestureP 
oints:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in file://C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster 
\com-initialtheta-theta/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will 
not be reattempted until the update interval of lib has elapsed or updates are 
forced
```

can any one help me out cos am running late

Comment: I have a stupid question that I must ask: Have you successfully built any maven artifacts in the workspace before?

Comment: It seems odd that you are using a snapshot release in your dependency statement, but the repository you are trying to get this from has snapshots disabled. I can't find a specific statement about how to set this up, but I bet this is not correct. One resource that might help is http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/maven.html.

Answer (score 0):

some things to try/confirm:

- Does the machine have access to the internet.  Don't just say it does. confirm it by pinging something remote.  Maven doesn't like not being able to access a repository
- In the pom editor, are there any error messages displayed?  Can you delete the dependency and add it using the add dependency dialog?
- Try putting the repository outside of the Eclipse workspace.  In theory it should work where it is but it's an odd place to have a repository and maven does not like "odd".
- Go to the repository root and confirm that the folder names exactly match the group id, artifact id and version for the dependency.